# Pass PHP value to ColdFusion

Tags: php, coldfusion, parameter-passing

I'm trying pass a value from PHP to a ColdFusion page using POST method. It's actually a form that has only one text field and submit button. The question is how to "catch" that value on the ColdFusion page to use it in SQL SELECT statement.

PHP page:

```
<form  action="adminlog.cfm" method="post">
  <input  type="text" name="admin"  placeholder="Admin" required >
  <input  type="submit" value="admin"/>
</form>
```

ColdFusion page:

```
<cfif Form.admin NEQ "">
  Client ID is still #Form.ClientID#
<cfelse>
  No value supplied for ClientID
</cfif>

<cfquery name='myQuery' datasource='MyDSN'>
  SELECT * FROM admin WHERE  aID = <cfparam name="Form.admin" />
</cfquery>
```

All I'm getting is:

> **Error Executing Database Query.** on line
>
> ```
> <cfquery name='myQuery' datasource='MyDSN'>
> ```

If I remove the WHERE condition from the SELECT statement id displays records from database no problem. So I guess it has to do with passing a parameter.

Comment: In  `<input  type="text" name="admin"  placeholder="Admin" required >`

"required" may not be doing anything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use cfqueryparam, not cfparam.

Also presumably you only want to do this query if they have supplied a value for that field.  Add it into your IF statement:

```
<cfif Form.admin NEQ "">    
     <cfquery name='myQuery' datasource='MyDSN'>
         SELECT * FROM admin 
         WHERE  aID = <cfqueryparam value="#Form.admin#" />
     </cfquery>
<cfelse>
       No value supplied for ClientID
</cfif>
```

Comment: Yes!!! Perfect!!! Thanks duncan!!! Another question - why my form already has a value in it when i open the page...?

Comment: To be thorough, you should specify a datatype in your queryparam tag.

Comment: @Dims - RE `cfif Form.admin NEQ ""`:  Just because the parameter is not empty does not mean it contains the expected value type. If the `aID` column is numeric (a date, etctera), verify `Form.admin` is too.